# Replaying SQL Server Trace for SqlBulkCopy Command

Tags: sql-server, trace, sqlbulkcopy, rml, replay

We are using RML Utilities (Ostress.exe) for replaying our trace workload, recently we found a query (insert bulk) - [1] in that trace file which is failing to replay since the data being inserted is not present in the captured trace file. After investigation we found out that SqlBulkCopy command is being fired by our application which streams the data to SqlServer and is responsible for the insert bulk statements in the trace file captured. Is there something (capture some specific event, column in trace definition) that we can do to capture the data or replay the trace?

Please let us know if you need more information on the same.

Thanks.

```
[1] insert bulk X_Table ([GeographyMapping_GeoId] NVarChar(100) COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, [GeographyMapping_ShapeId] NVarChar(255) COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, [GeographyMapping_ShapeIndex] NVarChar(255) COLLATE 
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, [GeographyMapping_Latitude] Float, [GeographyMapping_Longitude] 
Float, [GeographyMapping_Type] NVarChar(100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't replay bulk loads:

[Traces that contain operations on text, ntext, and image columns involving the bcp utility, the BULK INSERT, READTEXT, WRITETEXT, and UPDATETEXT statements, and full-text operations. These events are skipped.](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188238.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry but I've seen that already and we are able to capture the BulkInsert Query successfully but not the 'Insert Bulk' queries which are caused because of the SqlBulkCopy command.